# What is the code to exit/ stop VBscript from running in the event of a condition not being met?

Tags: vbscript

I have looked on Google and the answer is not there!

First things first. WScript.Quit DOES NOT WORK! I have no idea what "WScript" is but it clearly has nothing to do with client side scripting for a web page. I have seen this "WScript" thing somewhere before and it just produces errors (maybe obsolete or something) so please do not suggest it...

Anyway... all I wish to do is completely stop the script in the event of a condition not being met. Obviously I don't want "Exit Sub" because the code would then carry on running if that sub is embedded!

I am aware of the "stop" command but I am under the impression that it is only used for debugging.

Hopefully a very simple question.

UPDATE and Conclusion: Before I close this subject I will just expand a little on what I was trying to do...

I had a number of main subs that were being started by a button click. In order to make it so that I did not have to edit each individual sub I embedded a universal sub within each one that did a preliminary check.

Part of that preliminary check was to stop the program in the case of an incorrect user input. If an error was detected I wanted to halt all progress from that point on. An "exit sub" would obviously just skip the rest of that preliminary sub and the main sub would carry on executing.

In the end it was just a case of writing in an error flag (that is checked in the main subs) or incorporating the error condition operation in each main procedure. In that way you exit the main sub and the problem is solved.

It was not laziness - I just wanted to reduce the amount of code. Thank you for the responses anyway.

Comment: It would be equitable if people read the question first before putting a -1. Yes, I have researched - if the answer was available then I would not be here would I?

Comment: Ok - It may have been a bit ignorant of me not finding out what "WScript" was (I now know it means windows script) but either way it does not work. It will just give an error saying that that object (wscript) does not exist.

Comment: It may depend on what your script code is actually doing.  In many cases you may need to use "On Error Resume Next" to avoid an un-trapped error blowing up your code. But then you have to follow-up every error-capable statement with a check, such as "If err.Number <> 0 Then..."  Then you can "raise" the error your own way and exit using Wscript.Quit(n) (where 'n' is a number).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Sub MyFunc
    ----------
    My Code
    ----------
End Sub

Function Main
  On Error Resume Next
  MyFunc
  If Err.Number <> 0
  Exit Function
End Function
```

It'll stop executing the code, the point it finds an exception or throws an error.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that the WScript is always available if running a .vbs/.vbe/.wsf script using either the wscript.exe or cscript.exe engine.  When WScript is not available is if running using a different engine.  E.g. running VBScript within a HTA, a webpage, in VBA or from a hosted COM script control.

To exit a script which is not running from wscript.exe or cscript.exe, you can do something like the following:

```
main

Sub main
    ' execute code here

    ' oops a confition is not met:
    If Not condition then Exit Sub

    ' more code to execute if condition was met
End Sub
```

Comment: I may have been going around this the wrong way to begin with. It was not as if I could not carry out what I intended to do, it is just that I was under the impression that there must have been a way to stop the script from activating completely (to prevent the need to place the "exit sub" in each individual originating procedure). I think it was probably just lack of programming experience that lead me to think that I could just stop everything from one place. I have now just written the stop condition into each of the main procedures. I could maybe have incorporated an error flag instead.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way, What i found is: `WScript.Quit`

Answer (score 3):

*The Wscript object is only available if you are running in the Windows Script Host (wscript.exe,cscript.exe). NOT Internet Explorer (iexplorer.exe, mshta.exe)*

Well an easy way to do this is to declare a global variable that gets set to false until an error occured, and if the error occured then that variable will be set to true, after that anytime that variable gets checked you can exit sub\function\for\do\whatever.

Example:

```
Dim ErrorOccured
On Error Resume Next
ErrorOccured=False


Sub Main()
    If ErrorOccured Then Exit Sub
    'some code
    MsgBox "Main has run"
End Sub


Sub MakeAnError
    If ErrorOccured Then Exit Sub
    'some code
    Err.Raise 2
    If Err Then ErrorOccured=True
End Sub


Function TellMeRandom
    If ErrorOccured Then Exit Function
    'some code
    Randomize
    TellMeRandom =Int((100- 1+ 1) * Rnd + 1)*1
End Function


Function ResetError
    ErrorOccured=False
End Function



Call Main                 'Main will run because an error has not occured (ErrorOccured is False)

MsgBox TellMeRandom       'This will return a random number 1-100

Call MakeAnError          'This will set the Global ErrorOccured to true

MsgBox TellMeRandom       'This will be blank because the ErrorOccured prevented it from running

Call Main                 'This will not run because the ErrorOccured prevented it from running

Call ResetError           'This will set the Global ErrorOccured to false

Call Main                 'This will run because ErrorOccured is back to False

MsgBox TellMeRandom       'This will return a random number 1-100 because ErrorOccured is back to false
```

Just remember to Add `If ErrorOccured then Exit Sub` for a sub routine or `If ErrorOccured then Exit Function` for a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could also raise an error such as: `Err.Raise 507`

This Error will exit your current script : `"An exception occurred".`